# Get value of a non-public member of sender object

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection and all the examples I've seen says this should work. I'm trying to get the PortName property as shown here.

This returns null:

```
var port = this.GetType().GetProperty("PortName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
```

[image]

Comment: you need to follow the object graph, such as getting the `port` first from `plc`.

Comment: `PottingMachine.MyTestClass` does not have a `PortName` property.

Comment: While I'm not new to C#, this is my firs real OO app. I'll try to give some more info. MyTestClass creates a new plc object and a new CommandDispatcher object. My base class then uses the CommandDispatcher to send commands to the plc object

Comment: @EE_Kraig In that case you shouldn't be using reflection in the first place.  It's almost certainly the wrong solution to whatever problem you have.

Comment: and when it gets data back from the device, the CD throws an event that contains the data. This is where I'm trying to see what port responded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would like to get the value of the `PortName` property of the field `port` in `plc`, which by itself is a field of `this`

And what you are doing is trying to get a property named `PortName` from `this` which obviously does not exist there.

So lets get the field `port` inside `plc` and the get the value of `PortName`:

```
var field = 
    this.plc.GetType().GetField("port", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
SerialPort port = (SerialPort)field.GetValue(this.plc);
```

now you can use `port.PortName`

Comment: This works wonderfully!! A big thank you!